# MongoDB Compass: Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found

Tags: mongodb

Trying to perform the following query:

```
// $match...
{ 
  MetricName: {
    $regex: "\|"
  } 
}
```

Compass is giving me this error:

```
Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. It seems like aggregations in Compass hate regexes because I can make simple regex queries using the basic query editor but not inside Compass aggregations.

Comment: it expects `.aggregate([{$match:{...}}])`

Comment: Compass doesn't like your `"\"` backslash. What are you attempting? Have you tried escaping it with another backslash? Otherwise your syntax is correct.